# могут ли элементы массива влиять друг на друга?

Tags: c#

Допустим у меня есть несколько объектов класса, которые содержат в себе по таймеру на события которого подписаны и обработчики этого события. Могут ли они каким-то магическим образом друг на друга повлиять
(типа один класс выполнял код обработчика и в это время другой элемент вызвал этот код только содержащийся в нем и соответственно настроил его под себя, а первый этого не знал и продолжил выполняться с измененными данными)
внутри кода обработчика сработав почти одновременно?

Comment: Если у вас правильно прописаны области видимости методов и полей класса- не могут.

Comment: Откуда ж мы знаем что вы там написали. А вы показать не хотите, я правильно понял?

Comment: @АндрейNOP да кода и нет мне просто стало интересно могут ли такие вещи друг другу мешать.

Comment: @Anamnian но чисто теоретически такое возможно как я понял?

Comment: В шарпе возможности выстрелить в себе ногу поменьше чем скажем в плюсах (о, указатели!), но если вы специально зададитесь такой целью, то можете устроить себе (оно вам надо?) через глобальные/внешние по отношению к массиву вещей да в потоконебезопасных контекстах, в противном случае - нет, не могут, не занимайтесь мистикой.

Comment: @Сергей да, в принципе такое возможно.

Comment: @AK а как же `unsafe`?:) для любителей незащищенного... программирования!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Неявное влияние элементов обычно не очень хорошо, но возможно. Как простейший пример,

у нас есть менеджер для состояния

```
public class StateManager
{   
    public event EventHandler<int> StateShaged;
    public void OnStateChanged(int newState)
    {
        this.StateShaged?.Invoke(this, newState);
    }
}
```

Каждый элемент массива может быть таким:

```
public class ValueHolder
{
    StateManager _manager;
    public ValueHolder(StateManager manager)
    {
        _manager = manager;
        _manager.StateShaged += (sender, args) => 
        {
            this.Value = args;          
        };          
    }

    public void Boom()
    {
        _manager.OnStateChanged(15);
    }

    public int Value{get;set;}      
}
```

и сам код работы с этой красотой

```
var manager = new StateManager();
var array = Enumerable.Range(0, 5)
    .Select(x => new ValueHolder(manager) {Value = x})
    .ToArray();

foreach(var item in array) Console.WriteLine(item.Value);

array[0].Boom();

foreach(var item in array) Console.WriteLine(item.Value);
```

вывод в консоль

```
0
1
2
3
4
15
15
15
15
15
```

Как видите, напрямую каждый элемент не вызывает другой элемент, но взаимодействие происходит неявно.